# Trouble understanding Docker Compose environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a playground project for Docker Compose with the file like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8'
        container_name: '${PROJECT_NAME}_mysql'
        hostname: '${PROJECT_NAME}_mysql'
        networks:
            - internal
        ports:
            - '127.0.0.1:${MYSQL_EXPOSE_PORT}:3306'
        volumes:
            - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        env_file:
            -   ./mysql/.env
        environment:
            MYSQL_EXPOSE_PORT: '${MYSQL_EXPOSE_PORT}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${MYSQL_USER}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
volumes:
    mysql:

networks:
    internal:
```

My `./mysql/.env` is this:

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=foobar
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_USER=web
MYSQL_PASSWORD=web
```

And my `.env` file looks like this:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=foobar
PROJECT_NAME=foobar

MYSQL_EXPOSE_PORT=33061

MYSQL_DATABASE=foobar
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_USER=web_override
MYSQL_PASSWORD=web_override
```

I read somewhere that `env_file` and `environment` create variables that will be available in the container itself, and `--env-file` supplies variables that will be available during the processing of `docker-composer.yml` file.

But running the:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml --env-file .env up -d
```

produces, for me, unexpected behavior.

1. If I omit both the `env_file` and the `environment` configs, MySQL won't start due to an empty password. Variables from `--env-file` are ignored. Does that mean that `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` is in fact required as container env?
2. If I put `env_file` only, MySQL starts, but uses credentials from `./mysql/.env`. It silently ignores .env file supplied via `--env-file` option
3. Lastly, if I put both of `env_file` and `environment`, it will honor the value from `--env-file` due to variable substitution. But exec-ing into the container and echoing `$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` seems rarely ugly and screams security vulnerability waiting to happen.

It seems to me that I am having a fundamental misunderstanding of how Docker Compose env variables work.

Can someone please provide some sort of clarification to these questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two phases of processing environment variables:

1. At the Compose level, it takes its own environment, and also reads the [`docker compose --env-file` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/), or if you don't specify that option, `.env`.  It then uses these environment variables to do [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) in the `docker-compose.yml` file.
2. Each container has its own environment, as specified by the Compose [`environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment) or [`env_file:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) directives.

That means that setting something in the outer environment or putting it in the `--env-file` file (step 1) does not automatically make it visible to a container (step 2).

This is consistent with your observations.  In the first two cases, specifying `--env-file` doesn't put anything in the per-container configuration, it only affects the environment variable expansion, and so from the container's point of view it has no effect.  In the third case, you have the correct sequence: `--env-file` sets variables at the Compose level, variable substitution sets fixed strings in the `environment:` block, and then `environment:` [takes precedence](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) over `env_file:`.

Comment: Thank you. This kind of answer with those links is just what I seeked :)

Comment: some great answer. a hidden gem that AI cant really do like this... thanks